# SQL Equivalent of M Query Text.Contains

Tags: sql, powerbi, azure-sql-database

So we have built out a working model purely in Power BI loading lots of abstracts titles from published journals etc - and we need to know if specific Mentions of a string/word (Synonym) is within the abstract

In Power BI - this works fine for us with smaller volumes of data

`= Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Custom", "Mentions", each if Text.Contains([Concat_Title_Abstract],[Synonym],Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) then 1 else 0)`

We have now loaded the base data into an Azure SQL Server 12.0.2000.8 table as this is hundreds of millions of rows - and want to be able to do the same against each row, loaded into a table

Essentially, it needs to be a LIKE function, comparing a Synonym within the Abstract ([Concat_Title_Abstract])

I have tried using a full text index etc, but this can only be used after the FROM statement, it needs to be iterated at a row level...

Any ideas?

Comment: If you can specify the server you are using because how to concat differs.

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Azure SQL Server 12.0.2000.8